# How do i wrap my Dart result value with a Future?

Tags: dart

I have a function which returns a list of emails, but in side of it, it builds the list and tries to return it.

How do i return the list wrapped in a future?

```
Future<List<Email>> getEmails(){
  List<Email> emailList = new List<Email>();
    //loop to build a set of dummy data
  return emailList;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several options:

- you can wrap the returned value with `new Future<List<Email>>.value(emailList);`
- you can annotate the function body with the `async` keyword:

```dart
Future<List<Email>> getEmails() async {
  List<Email> emailList = new List<Email>();
    //loop to build a set of dummy data
  return emailList;
}
```

Comment: ahh, i knew i forgot the `async` tag.

Comment: It seems to still throw an error when i try this though.  Maybe im doing something wrong.  Still says `List<Email>` is not type `Future<List<Email>>`

Comment: It shouldn't be giving that warning if the method is marked as async. Can you show the exact code you are trying, e.g., on dartpad.dartlang.org.